Automatically reset database with Flyway in a spring-boot project using kotest extension
I have a basic spring-boot project written in Kotlin and using Flyway for handling database setup.
I want to write integration tests, all in a seperate source folder in src/integrationTest which I set up in gradle.
Now I want to create a kotest TestListener which recreates the database before each spec using flyway.
I was successful with wiring this manually like this:
@Component
class FlywayCleaningTestListener(
  private val flyway: Flyway
) : TestListener {
  override suspend fun beforeSpec(spec: Spec) {
    flyway.clean()
    flyway.migrate()
  }
}

@SpringBootTest
class RepositoryIntegrationTest(
  private val flywayCleaningTestListener: FlywayCleaningTestListener
) : FunSpec({
  extensions(flywayCleaningTestListener)

  test("foo") {
    // the test
  }
})

Now I want to go one step further and have this extension applied automatically to all tests in the integrationTest folder.
How can I do this, when the flyway object needs to be injected into the testlistener as a spring dependency?
An (abstract) base test class would also be fine.

If you want to reset database data between each test, annotating your test classes with @Transactional could be enough (More details in the second note in this page.
